# having problem with graphql and magic api . how to apply mutations and queries on a server to create a schema

Tags: vue.js, graphql, hasura, hasura-jwt, magic-sdk

I have two GraphQL files: `mutations.js` and `queries.js` under a `gql` folder...

This folder contains GraphQL mutations and queries used across the app.

```
 gql
   mutations.js
   queries.js
```

I set up the GraphQL endpoint, but i keep getting this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: GraphQL error: field "users" not found in type: 'query_root'

NB: None of the GraphQL queries or mutation contain errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added tables manually and added some rows after creating a Heroku PostgreSQL database, linking it to my hasura app, and putting this line in `.env`:

```
GRAPHQL_URI="https://definite-XXX-XX.hasura.app/v1/graphql"
```